# Count rows with single record

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these 2 tables which I would like to query:

```
create table active_pairs
(
    pair                  text,
    exchange_id           integer
);


create table exchanges
(                        
    exchange_id         integer
);

INSERT INTO active_pairs (pair, exchange_id)

VALUES ('London/Berlin', 2),
       ('London/Berlin', 3),
       ('Paris/Berlin', 4),
       ('Paris/Berlin', 3),
       ('Oslo/Berlin', 2),
       ('Huston/Berlin', 2);
       
INSERT INTO exchanges (exchange_id)

VALUES (2),
       (3),
       (4),
       (3),
       (2),
       (2);
```

I tried to use this SQL query to get records with single unique record for `pair` column:

```
SELECT COUNT(cp)
FROM active_pairs cp
    INNER JOIN exchanges ce on cp.exchange_id = ce.exchange_id
HAVING COUNT(pair) = 1
```

I should get as a result `2` for `Oslo/Berlin` and `Huston/Berlin` because they are unique.

But I get empty result. Can you advise me how I can fix this?

Comment: Post data sample and expected output!

Comment: Please post sample datas and expected result

Comment: Do you mean the count of the distinct rows? I.e. there can be two rows, but if they are identical you want to count it?

Comment: I updated the post. @HoneyBadger yes, correct.

Comment: Why do you join to `exchanges`? All the data that you need exists in `active_pairs`.

Comment: Your data modeling seems false. The Many to Many relation doesn't seem to make sense

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to get values for `pair` that are used only once:

```
SELECT pair FROM active_pairs GROUP BY pair HAVING count(*) = 1
```

And then to count that:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (
    SELECT pair FROM active_pairs GROUP BY pair HAVING count(*) = 1
)
```

(There are probably more efficient ways to do that, just this came to my mind first.)

Answer (score 0):

You can `group by pair` in the table `active_pairs` to filter only the `pair`s that occur only once and with `COUNT()` window function you can count them:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) OVER () counter
FROM active_pairs
GROUP BY pair
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8036f00ad3f2e3b25e4eb0c8e2382fd3).

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be

```
select pair,count(*)
from active_pairs
group by pair
having count(*) = 1
```

The above query will give you

```
Oslo/Berlin   1
Huston/Berlin 1
```

Now just put count over this query

```
select count(*) from
(select pair,count(*)
from active_pairs
group by pair
having count(*) = 1) a
```

This will give you answer 2 i.e. number of unique pairs in the table

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can understand the question, you would like to have something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT pair)
FROM active_pairs;
```

If you want to see unique values in other columns then just add `, COUNT(DISTINCT your_column)`

Answer (score -1):

2?

```
-- what data is being queried (removed the WHERE)
SELECT COUNT(cp)
FROM active_pairs cp
INNER JOIN exchanges ce on cp.exchange_id = ce.exchange_id
```

first I removed the WHERE, but that gives:

| count |
| --- |
| 14 |

```
-- added `GROUP BY pair`
SELECT pair, count(cp)
FROM active_pairs cp
GROUP BY pair
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Wait, I should use GROUP BY:

| pair | count |
| --- | --- |
| Huston/Berlin | 1 |
| Oslo/Berlin | 1 |

Then maybe add the last column to get `2`?:

```
SELECT SUM(cp)
FROM (
   SELECT pair, count(cp) as cp
   FROM active_pairs cp
   GROUP BY pair
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) x
```

Yes, result is: `2` !

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=71342d8b7f02586380d69a892bcc27cf)

Answer (score -1):

```
select   count(*) over ()
from     active_pairs
group by pair
having   count(*) = 1
limit    1
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=74bac92a0495ad164112a26c997881a4)